# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) Saving Edit Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got the following entity framework error while trying to save edit page

**"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."**

```
_db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified; 
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Here is my Edit Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
{
   try
      {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
             _db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
             _db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
           }
       }
   catch (DataException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again,      
        and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }

    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(_db.Categories, "CategoryId",  
                      "CategoryName", product.CategoryId);

    return View(product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_db.Entry(product).State = product.Id == 0 :EntityState.Add ? EntityState.Modified;
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

Modify only works if product is already there. if not add instance of product in db.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to delete a record that is not already there.

You can catch this exception by doing the following

```
var prdct= db.products.Find(product.id);
if(prdct != null)
{
    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}else
{
    return NotFound();
}
```